# How can I make Input element read-only depends the value of two variable

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to make input element read-only depending the value of two variable. I have two variable  'isdisabled',  'isNaDisbled' . if one of the value is true , then Input element and its span element should readonly attribute giving OR condition. Please give a help

Here is the code

```html
for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
        var isdisabled = false;
        var isNaDisbled = false;
        if (Model.[i].IsProtected || Model.[i].IsNotEnabled)
        {
                 isdisabled = Model.attendanceLogList[i].IsProtected;
         }
        
        if (Model.[i].IsClockingEnabled)
        {
              isNaDisbled = Model.attendanceLogList[i].IsClockEnabled;
        }
     <td>
                        <div >
                           <span><input type="checkbox" readonly="@(isdisabled ? "readonly" : null) " asp-for="@Model.attendanceLogList[i].IsNormalAttendance" /></span>
                            <input type="number" readonly="@(isdisabled ? "readonly" : null)"  placeholder="0.00" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:central" class="form-control format-text" asp-for="@Model.[i].NormalHrs" />
                        </div>
    </td>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var isdisabled = false;
var isNaDisbled = true;
var rd1 = isdisabled ? "disabled" : null;
var rd2 = isNaDisbled ? "readonly" : null;
<p><input type="checkbox" @rd1/></p>
<p><input type="number" @rd2/></p>
```

There is a simple example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/DJ9URi

Comment: If isdisabled or If isnadisbled = true  then I want to make Input readonly  otherwise it should be editable

Comment: Sorry there is a correction in my original post